# WordPress load related posts using tags not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a WordPress PHP code to get related posts of a current post, but when i use this code it shows only current post

My code is below

```
$posttags = wp_get_post_tags(get_the_id(), array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ));

        $args = array( 
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'tax_query'      => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
                        'field'     => 'slug',
                        'terms'     => $posttags
                    )
                )
            );

        $postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

can anyone help me to get other related posts using current posts tags. Thank You

website url is http://felixwky.com/day-0-experiment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this link for more details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

```
<?php
// For use in the loop, list 3 post titles related to first tag on current post
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

if ($tags) {
    echo 'Related Posts';

    $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;

    $args = array(
        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'caller_get_posts' => 1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```