# How to Display related Posts via Tag in Wordpress Posts in right sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Expert

I need to display posts that are assigned by Tag in post but not below the post content it should be displayed in the right sidebar.

summary: I want to display posts by tag inside wordpress post in the right-sidebar widget area.

**Note:** The related posts should be displayed fetch Tag from the same Post assign to it. Thanks.

example: [image]

In the screenshot you see there is a post with tag "italy" and it display all posts from tag "Italy" in the same post in right-sidebar area.

I hope you have got the point. Thanks and hope to see your reply soon with coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress load related posts using tags not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810179/wordpress-load-related-posts-using-tags-not-working)

Comment: While the link above isn't exactly what you're looking for, the code from the accepted answer does exactly what you need: retrieves a list of posts that are using the same tag as the current post. Use that as a starting point to find your own solution (and also please do some research before asking questions here).

Comment: @cabrerahector i follow your given link but not working the code provided in the given link. I added the code to single.php in theme customization but not working...could you kindly help me..

Comment: You either need to add that code somewhere inside [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop) or somehow pass the ID of the current post (eg. via [get_the_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)) to the script for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a very efficient way to do it, using "The Wordpress Way" (with Shortcodes). The sortcode name is **The Display Posts** Shortcode, it allows you to add a list of your blog posts to different pages. Using Arguments you can display specific posts based on their categories or tags.

**In order to use it on your sidebar, you must add a text widget and then add this shortcode inside inside the widget.**

Now, once you have done that. You must add the arguments to display only the posts with you "Italy" tag.

Arguments are used to customize how the posts are displayed.

**Argument**

Specify the tag slug (or comma separated list of tag slugs).
The default is empty.
Example:

```
    [display-posts tag="tag1, tag2"]
```

This shortcode is pretty amazing, you can add a lot of different types of filters for your posts. I advice you to read the whole article in:

https://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

Know, if you want to update the shortcode differently for each post, you would have to develop a PHP Snippet to add this logic to the text widget.

Snippet:

```
add_filter('widget_text','execute_php',100);
    function execute_php($html){
         if(strpos($html,"<"."?php")!==false){
              ob_start();
             eval("?".">".$html);
              $html=ob_get_contents();
              ob_end_clean();
         }
        return $html;
    }
```

Then, add this to the text widget. Should get the slug by getting the queried object while on the tag page, like this more or less

```
<?php
    $tag = get_queried_object();
    $post_tag = $tag->slug
    echo $"<[display-posts tag=".$post_tag."]"

?
```

Hope this can help you with your blog, cheers!

Comment: i agree with what you shared.....but there is a problem, i will manually add tag value to the shortcut to each post...means:     [display-posts tag="Italy"] for next post i will add shortcut with tag [display-posts tag="japan"] and so on...So better to add the shortcut once in right-sidebar area and it auto fetch tag from the current post...is there any way to do it ?

Comment: The fast way: You can enable Wordpress Full Width for your blog post, and copy the shortcode in a second column for a block, and then create a new block and continue writing normally.

Comment: The hard way: develop a PHP Snippet to use php logic on text widget, and then dynamically generate a $variable for the post tag and add it to the shortcode as html

Comment: I have edited my answer with how it would be the hard way. It should be a good base to help you complete your objective

Comment: the code you provide above is not adding to wordpress widget let it check in the screenshot here: https://prnt.sc/pk7kjh

Comment: This code [display-posts tag="App"] works in wordpress post editor but not working in the wordpress widget..so how to add this shortcut in wordpress widget